Dynamic function weights
Are dynamic weights possible to implement?
When running benchmarks, the weights are returned. But there are parameters that are updateable while the blockchain is running and within on_initialize the weights are hardcoded by running the exact function on_initialize runs in a testing environment and simply copying and pasting it into on_initialize return.
If the parameters are updated, it will either increase or decrease the resulting weight if benchmarks are ran with the new parameters.
What ways are there is dynamically implement dynamic weights or somehow update weights when params are updated?

In short, any components that can influence the weight should be added to the weight function as a component.
For example, in the case of on_initialize, if it depends in block_number and an arbitrary 3rd party value like c2, the benchmark function should look like:
#[benchmark]
fn on_init(
    b: Linear<1, MAX_BLOCK_NUMBER>,
    c2: Linear<1, MAX_FOR_C2>,
) -> Result<(), BenchmarkError> {
    // write your benchmark such that the complexity is captured by `b` and `c2`.
}

And this will always be used as <T as WeightInfo>::on_init(block_number, c2_value)

thanks for the response. do you have examples of this implemented anywhere? Im wondering how exactly to do this? in the benchmarking.rs file? In this specific case, there are multiple for loops performed that depend on 2 storage values and these 2 storage values can be updated by the sudo or governance.

To add.  right now the weights are calculated using benchmarks! {}

currently if the weights cant dynamically be generated the thought was to generate weights based on the max values the storage items can be. since the high weighted functions are only called once ever x blocks. then when not called return a smaller weight based on the queried variables it calls each on_initialize
